# Не записывается значение в регистр rcx

Tags: gnu-assembler

```
.global _start
.text
_start:
     mov     $_length, %rcx
     mov     $60, %rax
     xor     %rdi, %rdi
     syscall
_length:
     .long 0x000005
```

Сборка:

> as -g -mintel64 -march=corei7 -mtune=corei7 -v -o example.o example.s

> ld -Ofast -o example example.o

Далее:

> gdb example

> break 7

> r

> i r

Смотрим - в регистре rcx записано большое число, а нужно 5.
Почему?

Comment: Попробуйте без знака доллар т.е. вот так mov _length, %rcx или movl _length, %rcx

Comment: Так другое число в регистре - 5. Похоже, что верное.